# Process data from on-premise SQL Server with cloud functions?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, vpn, google-cloud-vpn

My client has his data stored on SQL Server hosted on an on-premise network. I established a VPN connection from Google to the network, but I don't know how to follow from here. My final goal is to process his data using cloud functions. Any suggestions?

PS: I read that Shared VPC can be used to accomplish this, but I don't have a proper organization for this purpose :/

Edit: I followed the suggestions on the comments but now I'm missing to extract the data since pyodbc is not pre-installed on Cloud Functions. Any ideas oh how to query an on-prem database on SQL Server through Cloud Functions?

Comment: Are you using `Cloud Interconnect` or `Cloud VPN` to connect on-premises? If yes, then configure `Serverless VPC Access`. You will then be about to connect from Cloud Functions to on-premises SQL server. Edit your question with more details. Read this link for more information: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access

Comment: Serverless VPC connector is the correct solution. In addition, be sure that your routing and firewall rules are OK.

Comment: I am using Cloud VPN to connect to the network. I configured the Serverless VPC Access and built a function using this VPC. It should be working, but I'm missing a way to test the connection since my script was built using pyodbc and this packaged is not installed on Cloud Functions. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: @SebastianTinoco: Spending some time reading the docs on how to install the packages for your cloud function will go a long way.

Comment: Use  Cloud Run, it's almost the same thing, but you have a container, and you can install easily what you want in your container.